# jquery dialog() with form - select an option opens a new dialog box when click "ok"

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a dialog box with two radio select options 'exist' and 'upload' and an ok button. When you click ok, depending on what radio button you have selected I want a different dialog box to show. I tried the code below so when you select 'exist' a box opens with the html id=chooseImage but I can't get it to work. 
How do I do this? 
This is my code:

```
        $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" )
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Add Images",
                buttons: {"Okay": function() {$("#form").submit();  
                     if($("#exist").is(":checked")) {          
            //need to add some code to show new dialog box; 

                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                 }

                         if($("#upload").is(":checked")) {
            // need to add some code to show new dialog box; 
                            // doesn't work $("#chooseImage").dialog( title: "hello");
                            $(this).dialog("close"); }
                        }},
                //{"Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }},
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false 
        });

        $("#addImage")
            .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog("open");
        });
        });     
        }); 

          '<div id="chooseImage">' self::chooseFromExisiting($dbr); '</div>'
```

When I load the page the functions   chooseFromExisiting($dbr) and  uploadImage() load with the page and you can see the HTML.  getFormHtml() doesn't and only shows when you click the 'add image' button. I want   chooseFromExisiting($dbr) and  uploadImage()  also to only show when you select them and click the 'okay' button.

```
       public static function fnAddImages(){
    global $wgOut, $wgHooks, $wgUser,  $wgRequest;


     // import addimage javascript and css files
      $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript" src="extensions/AddImages/addimages.js"></script>');
      $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript" src="extensions/AddImages/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>');
      $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript" src="extensions/AddImages/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>');
      $wgOut->addScript('<link type="text/css" href="extensions/AddImages/css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />');      
      $wgOut->addScript("<style>@import url( extensions/AddImages/style.css);</style>");

      //Add Image button with popup onclick
    $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript"> 

        ( function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                //var exist = $( "#exist" );//var upload = $( "#upload" );

                $( "#dialog-form" )
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Add Images",
                    buttons: {"Okay": function() {$("#form").submit();
                    if($("#exist").is(":checked")) {
                                 $(this).dialog("close");                           
                                $("#chooseImage").dialog("open");
                                $("#chooseImage")
                                    .dialog({
                                    autoOpen:false,
                                    title: "Choose from existing Images",
                                    draggable: false,
                                    //resizable: false,
                                    height: "auto",
                                    width: 460
                                    });
                                };
                        if($("#upload").is(":checked")) {
                            $( "#chooseImage" ).hide();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $("#uploadImage").dialog("open");
                                $("#uploadImage")
                                    .dialog({
                                    autoOpen:false,
                                    title: "Upload Image",
                                    height: "auto",
                                    width: 460
                                    });

                                     };  


                    }},
            });     

            $("#addImage")
                .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog("open");
            });
            }); 
            }); 
            } ) ( jQuery );

    </script>'); 
    //add from exisiting
    $wgOut->addHTML('<div id="chooseImage">');
     $out = self::chooseFromExisiting($dbr);
     $wgOut->addHtml($out);   
    $wgOut->addHTML('</div>');

    //upload image
    $wgOut->addHTML('<div id="uploadImage">'); 
      $form = self::uploadImage();   
      $wgOut->addHtml($form);
    $wgOut->addHTML('</div>');

    //form 
    $wgOut->addHTML('<div id="dialog-form">'); 
       $form = self::getFormHtml();   
       $wgOut->addHtml($form);
    $wgOut->addHTML('</div>');

    $wgOut->addHTML('<button id="addImage">Add Image</button>');


    //retun true to run hook function  
    return true;

}
    public static function getFormHtml(){
    global $wgOut;   

    $wgOut->addHTML('<form>
        <input type="radio"  name="addimage" value="exists already" id="exist"> Choose from Exisiting
        <br />
            <input type="radio"  name="addimage" value="upload now" id="upload"> Upload your Own
        </form>'); 

    }   


    public static function chooseFromExisiting( $dbr ){
    global $wgOut;      

        $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript"> 

        ( function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {          
            $( "#alignment" )
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Align Images",
                    //draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {"Okay": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}},

            });

            $("#imageSetting")
                .click(function() {
                $( "#alignment" ).dialog("open");
            });
            });     
            }); 
        } ) ( jQuery );

    </script>'); 

    $wgOut->addHTML('<div id="alignment">'); 
      $form = self::alignment();   
      $wgOut->addHtml($form);
    $wgOut->addHTML('</div>');
    //$wgOut->addHTML('<button id="imageSetting">Add</button>');


     $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
     $results = $dbr->query("SELECT DISTINCT  img_name, img_description, img_width, img_height, img_user_text, img_timestamp
            FROM wiki_image
            ORDER BY img_timestamp ASC
        "); 

    $uploaded = array();
    while( $row = $dbr->fetchObject( $results ) ) {
    $uploaded[] = array( $row->img_name, $row->img_width, $row->img_height, $row->img_user_text, $row->img_description);        
    }

    $wgOut->addHtml('<table><tr><td></td><th>Name</th><th>Thumbnail</th><th>Dimensions</th><th>User</th><th>Comment</th></tr>'); 

    foreach($uploaded as $upload){
    $wgOut->addHTML('<tr><td><button id="imageSetting">Add</button></td><td>');     
    $wgOut->addHTML($upload[0]);
    $wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>'); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('thumnail image'); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>'); 
    $wgOut->addHTML($upload[1]); 
    $wgOut->addHTML('x'); 
    $wgOut->addHTML($upload[2]); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>');
    $wgOut->addHTML($upload[3]); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>');
    $wgOut->addHtml('comment');
    $wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>'); 
    }

    $wgOut->addHtml('</table>');
    }

    public static function alignment(){
    global $wgOut;  

        $wgOut->addHtml('<form>'); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('<table>');
    // image setting
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<tr><td>Image Setting </td></tr>" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"400x400\" id=\"size\"    size=\"23\" maxlength=\"12\" onkeyup=\"createMarkup(this)\" onmouseout=\"createMarkup(this)\"/> px (width x height)</td></tr>" );
    // radio buttons for alignment left/center/right
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<tr> <td>Alignment: </td> </tr>" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<tr><td>");
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"left\" name=\"position\" value=\"left\" onchange=\"createMarkup(this)\"/>left" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "</td><td>");
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"center\" name=\"position\" value=\"center\" onchange=\"createMarkup(this)\"/>center" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "</td><td>" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"right\" name=\"position\" value=\"right\" checked=\"checked\"  onchange=\"createMarkup(this)\"/>right" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "</td></tr>" );
    $wgOut->addHTML( "<tr><td>" );
    //wgOut->addHtml('<input type="submit" value="OK" name="" id=""/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="close" />'); 
    $wgOut->addHTML( "</td></tr>" );
    $wgOut->addHtml('</table>'); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('</form>');

    }

    public static function uploadImage(){
    global $wgOut;  

        $wgOut->addHtml('Upload an Image from your computer'); 
    }
```

Comment: If you submit a form you will get redirected to another page. `$("#form").submit();`

Comment: If seems to work and not reload the page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work indeed because of syntax error: `$("#chooseImage").dialog( title: "hello");` You should check the console for any errors.

You need to encapsulate the parameters within `{}` brackets:

`$("#chooseImage").dialog({title: "hello"});`

Comment: thanks that saved me a lot of headache! It works now. The only thing is the html within the <div id=chooseImage> is showing on the screen when I load the page and then it moves to the dialog box when I select 'exist' and click ok. How do I not show it on the main page at all? I only want it to come up in the popup. Thanks.

Comment: Can u please update your question and include the HTML part of that `div#chooseImage` as well?

Comment: I just noticed I can only use the 'add image' dialog box once if I try and select 'exist' again nothing happens the second time.

Comment: Did you try `.dialog("open");` ?

Comment: I put that in now  if($("#exist").is(":checked")) {       $(this).dialog("close");                   $("#chooseImage").dialog("open");      $("#chooseImage").dialog({title: "Choose from existing Images", and I can open the dialog box multiple times. I'm just stuck on why the #chooseImage loads initially with the page. It is strange b/c the '#dialog-form' doesn't and the codes are structured the same. Thanks for your help

Comment: There is an option called `autoOpen`. Set it to false when creating the dialog for the first time: `.dialog({autoOpen:false});`

Comment: I tried that it doesn't stop the html showing up on the page when the page loads. It works for the first dialog box not not from any that I call later.

Comment: I've added all my code at the top. Is it anything to do with $("#form").submit();?

Comment: You need to call `.dialog({...})` on each element you want to convert into a jQuery UI dialog when the page loads or at least hide them by default `<div style="display:none" ...>`

Comment: could you show me an example in my code how this would work? I'm not sure what you mean. I tried $wgOut->addHTML('<div id="chooseImage">');
 $wgOut->addHtml('hello');  
 $wgOut->addHTML('</div>'); and the same thing happened. 'hello' loaded with the page and I had to click 'okay' twice on the 'add images' dialog box for $("#chooseImage").dialog() to show the text.

Comment: Either try `$("#chooseImage").dialog({autoOpen:false})` or `$wgOut->addHTML('<div id="chooseImage" style="display:none">')` and then open the dialog when necessary: `$("#chooseImage").dialog("open")`

Comment: Thank you SO much, it works with the style=display:none. I really appreciate your help. With regard to your first comment ' 
If you submit a form you will get redirected to another page. $("#form").submit();' I'm not sure what it means. I don't want to reload the page as I'm inserting an image to the text and I want to save it at the end when I've made all the changes. Is this the correct code to use? It doesn't seem to reload when I click 'ok'

Comment: When you fill out a form and you click on the submit button the form will be send to the page that was defined in the `action` attribute of the form and the page usually reloads. There might be such scenarios when it doesnt but that's another story. If it works for you, then it's okay. Anyway, would you mind to accept my answer above as the solution? It would be great for me! Thanks!